# Generate random inside a loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, random, lateral-join

I want to execute several times (lets say 30) an "experiment" that involves random numbers

My approach was:

```
select  
  rnd  
from 
  generate_series(0,30) as l,   -- number of times
lateral (
  select random() as rnd -- the "experiment"
) as t ;
```

You can read this as "*Execute 30 times the experiment*".

The problem is that that code generates 30 *exact* numbers.

Please **NOTE**: The "experiment" part obviously is more complex, but somewhere in it, it creates hundreds the random numbers per *experiment run*. i.e. I want to generate those hundreds of random numbers, 30 times. This is important, because I know that I could execute

```
select random() from generate_series(0,30)
```

and get 30 different random numbers, but that is *not* what I intend to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the `LATERAL` query does not depend on the left table expression, so PostgreSQL evaluates it only once.

To evaluate it once for each row in the left table expression, introduce a dependency:

```
SELECT rnd
FROM generate_series(0,30) as l   -- number of times
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT l.l * 0 + random() AS rnd -- the "experiment"
) AS t;
```